# Update query not setting value in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the below script running as part of a password forgot system. Everything seems to be working fine except that the database is not being updated with the 'token'. As everything else is working fine (i.e. $str is being set and used in the URL sent via email)... i think this must be a problem with the update script but I cant see why. My code is below, all help greatly appreciated.

```
if(isset($_POST["sign"])){
                include('connections/conn.php');

                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);

                $data = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM travisor_tradesperson WHERE email='$email'");

                if ($data-> num_rows > 0) {
                    $str = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
                    $str = str_shuffle($str);
                    $str = substr($str, 0, 10);
                    $url = "http://rhamilton461.web.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/travisor/passReset.php?token=$str&email=$email";

                    mail($email, "Reset Password", "To reset your password please visit: $url" , "From: rhamilton461@qub.ac.uk\r\n");

                    $conn->query("UPDATE travisor_tradesperson SET token = '$str' WHERE email='$email'");

                    echo "Please check your email.";

                } else {
                    echo "Please check your inputs.";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Print out the statement and try it in mysql console or Check if all values are set as expected

Comment: Had you bother to check if the sql query was successful and print out the error message if it was not for dubugging purposes, you would not have had to ask this question...

Comment: the sql was fine, I changed to use mysqli_query and it seems to work now. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try out to run script by commenting the calling statement of mail function.
it is possible that your table is not updating because there is error in mail function.
are you getting output as "**Please check your email**" ???

Comment: It looks much more a comment than an actual answer.